# Microsoft oauth screen is not resized during in WebBrowser control on WP device

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, oauth, webbrowser-control

I perform Microsoft oauth in my Windows Phone 8 application. We have a backend part which sends me an URL like this https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id=XXX&scope=wl.emails&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://myredirecthere/

I put this URL to WebBrowser control and show it on page. The problem is that the loaded page is not resized correctly - i must zoom-in when it is loaded. Could you suggest any ideas how to fix that?
Thanks!

The screenshot may be accessed from here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/m3gfgvy0lrx9urk/wp_ss_20140921_0001.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it was just simple. When i added

```
display=touch
```

inside the URL - everything worked fine and the browser content stretched the screen as i needed.